# Batch File to test if there are unsaved open Notepad files?

Tags: windows

I have found Batch File commands that test purely if Notepad is running at all.

But is there a way to test if there are *unsaved* open Notepad files?

I have noticed that all Notepad files have a title that ends with "- Notepad", and unsaved Notepad files have a title that starts with "*".

Could this pattern be used? Or maybe there is some other test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, the following line seems to do the trick.

```
set "np_us=F" & tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /v|find "*" >NUL && set "np_us=T"
```

This will return a value of np_us=T if there are Notepad windows with unsaved content open (i.e. ones that have an asterisk in the title), or np_us=F if either Notepad is not running, or there are no Notepad windows with unsaved content open.

There are probably better ways to test the matter, but I have been using the above for a few months and it has yet to my knowledge to throw up a false result.